# APi, returning the data and not an acknowledgement

Tags: node.js

I'm creating an API for an IoT-project, using Node.js.
I want the system to respond to certain commands, but the problem is that I only receive the acknowledgement.

This...

[image]

...should return this instead:
[image]

The server takes a couple of seconds to reply - and it's this reply, I want returned in the browser.

The gateway is configured with a simple Node-server, that listens on port 2002 and submits preformatted requests to port 2001, like this:

```
app.get("/neighborListRequest", (req, res) => {
    submitCommandToNC('{"objectType":"neighborListRequest"}', req, res); // <-- preformatted request
});


app.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("ERROR", err);
    }
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

function submitCommandToNC(cmd, req, res) {
    const client = net.createConnection({ port: 2001 }, () => {
        client.write(cmd); // <-- Submit the request
    });
    client.on('data', (data) => { // <-- get the reply
        console.log(data.toString());
        client.end();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(data); // <-- acknowledges request, but does not return the actual data
        
    });
    client.on('end', () => {
        //console.log('CLIENT: I disconnected from the server.');
    });
}
```

Any idea on, how to return the data, marked in yellow - and not the request itself? I tried putting in a timeout, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `res.end(data)` with `res.send(data)` or `res.json(data)`?

Comment: Yes, res.send(data) still returns the acknowledgement, res.json(data) does the same, except as decimals... {"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,111,98,106,101,99,116,84... etc.

Comment: Wait a minute, I might have made a grave mistake - the gateway-software that communicates with the other devices communicate on port 2000 (outgoing) and 2001 (ingoing) - so the data are returned on port 2000, not 2002 from which the request is made in the browser.

I need some additional code to listen on port 2000 as well and return these data instead, rather than the acknowledgement. Sorry for not mentioning the outbound port.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way - not the prettiest, but seems to do the job.

Any request on port 2002 sends a command to port 2001 and waits for answer at port 2000. An interval returns any answer from port 2000 to the browser at 2002 when "serverreply" is something else than null.

```
function submitCommandToNC(cmd, req, res) {
    var serverreply = "";
    const clientreceive = net.createConnection({ port: 2000 }, () => {

    });
    clientreceive.on('data', (data) => {
        serverreply = data.toString();
        // we've received the correct data from other devices. Hand them over to port 2002          
    });
    
    const client = net.createConnection({ port: 2001 }, () => {
        client.write(cmd);
    });
    client.on('data', (data) => {
        //console.log(data.toString());
        client.end();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (serverreply) {
                res.end(serverreply); // <-- This hands the data back to the browser
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        },1000);
    });
    client.on('end', () => {
        //console.log('CLIENT: I disconnected from the server.');
    });
}
```